Azure Form Recognitition; detection of currency seems rather inaccurate, api version: 2024-02-29-preview
wondering if someone has encountered this and/or knows of a way to make currency detection more accurate.
I have an app that is scanning invoices.
The attached invoices is CHF (Swiss Franc), but the TotalTax value (and others) is detected as EUR.

Where did EUR come from I wonder?  Did the form recognizer put that in there because the vendor address (right at the bottom of each page) is Ireland?  If that's true I would imagine the big fat "16 CHF" would have precedence?  Or could I make it be that way?
If anyone has an idea about how I can nudge the recognizer in a direction here, that'd be great. Thank you!


wondering if someone has encountered this and/or knows of a way to make currency detection more accurate.


If you can check the above picture even, I also got the same currency code which you get.
Here please check below locations/country names supported languages for pre-built invoice.
Thanks @Vasavi for the information.


There was an issue with the form recognizer while analyzing currency code. Have a look on this.

There was the only approach right now is Pre-processing

Before feeding the document into Azure Form Recognizer, consider pre-processing it to remove or minimize the influence of textual mentions of currency types. This could involve using text extraction techniques to identify and remove currency mentions, or applying regular expressions to filter out non-numeric characters.

